# How to idiomatically add element to immutable set and get if success?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an immutable set that tracks a set of Subscribers. This is the method that adds the Subs and return a Boolean to indicate if the subscription was actually processed:

```
var subs = Set.empty[Sub]
def addSub(addr: String, sub: Sub): Boolean = {
  if(subs.contains(sub)) {
    false
  }
  else {
    subscribe(addr)
    subs += sub
    true
  }
}
```

However this code is very "Java-like". I tried to make it more Scala/Functional but could not find a way, as assignment in Scala does not return the value so `subs += sub` has to be in its own line of code and makes it look like Java. How should I do to improve it?

I am aware that `mutable.Set.add()` actually return Boolean. But how to do this with `immutable.Set`?

Comment: Could you give more context to the code? You claim you want to do this functionally, but your code sample hinges on using mutable state. There is no pure functional way to mutate state, because as soon as you do so, it is no longer pure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala/Functional way is to use local scope, whenever possible, in order to keep everything immutable and to avoid side effects.

```
def addSub(addr :String, sub :Sub, subs :Set[Sub]): (Boolean, Set[Sub]) = {
  if(!subs(sub)) subscribe(addr)
  (!subs(sub), subs + sub)
}
```

usage:

```
val (subAdded, newSubs) = addSub(address, subscriber, oldSubs)
```

Comment: The transition from imperative to functional thinking is often difficult (even painful). If you have a single `Set[Sub]` that maintains state then, by definition, every modification is a side effect. Code that inspects `subs` can receive it as a passed parameter. Code that modifies `subs` can return a new/modified copy. That way the set of subs is always local and immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var` vs `val` on your set.  You can then do the following to check for the property and add it if it's not there.

```
var set = Set.empty[Sub]
set
  .find(_ == newVal) // checks for the property and converts to an Option[Sub] presence
  .fold[Boolean] {
    set = set + newVal // property is not in set, add and return true
    true
  }(_ => false) // property is set, return false
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using true/false literals? since it is dependent on contains/find result

Comment: Rather than using the literals, you could set the result of `fold` to be an `Option[Unit]` and call `exists()` after the fold.  But I personally view that as syntactic sugar over just returning the literals.

Comment: OP asked for a functional solution, but this uses a mutable variable.